# how to set Radio button value when it is in group?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can we get or set checked status of a radio buttion in radio group?

```
xyzButtoninGroup.setChecked(true)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this code explains itself

```
 int count = radioGroup.getChildCount();
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        View o = radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (o instanceof RadioButton) {

            RadioButton radioBtn =  (RadioButton)o;
            // get the state 
            boolean isChecked = radioBtn.isChecked()
            // to set the check
            radioBtn.setChecked(true);

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

each button has its own ID.  You set it by its id (the others will uncheck if they are in the same group, on their own)